# Integrate Intro.js with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intro.js

How can I integrate intro.js with react hooks?

The only documented examples (even on stack overflow) are for the `componentDidMount` etc methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little context on your question but you most certainly could.

FYI. I'm not familiar with introJS or it's API so I'll make up some stuff :)

For example, if you wanted the equivalent of starting on componentDidMount, you'd do:

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    // Get intro JS started
    introJs.init();
  },
  [] // Notice the empty array. This will only run when component mounts.
)
```

However, if you have something more dynamic, you need to tell intro.js about DOM updates performed by React. Simplest example would be to recreate introJS on every update.

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    // Get intro JS started
    introJs.init();
    // Destroy intro JS when component changes happen
    return () => introJs.destroy()
  }
  // Notice no dependencies array. This will run on every update.
)
```

This will essentially re-create introJS every component update - which may or may not be quite what you want/need.

You may use `useEffect` with specific dependencies that might require introJS to get updated, you may use `refs` to get the latest elements and send them to your introJS, you may use `useState` to keep track of the step number of introJS so you can start it back where your user left off, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install both "intro.js" and "introjs-react" into your package.json.
Then you can continue with guideline in website for intro.js-react.